# Dynamic insertion in object javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have defined data like an array of objects:

```
{"Driver":a, "Lap":b, "Position":c}
```

I want with a loop to insert in the same row all the drivers for each lap (into another data). For example:

```
        {"Lap":1,"Driver1":2,"Driver2":1,"Driver3":3}
        {"Lap":2,"Driver1":1,"Driver2":2,"Driver3":3}
        {"Lap":3,"Driver1":3,"Driver2":2,"Driver3":1}    
        {"Lap":4,"Driver1":2,"Driver2":1,"Driver3":3}
```

I know the number of the Laps (in variable maxLaps) and the number of the drivers on variable numDrivers.

I want to make that in a loop because the number of the laps and drivers change in different cases, so I need to do my code generic

Comment: make sure all of your datas are good and do your code really generic

Comment: Why don't you use an array instead of separate `DriverX` properties?

Answer (score 0):

Define a Javascript object like:

```
var myObject = { "Driver": a, "Lap": b, "Position": c };
```

Add new properties to this object as:

```
myObject.newProperty = d; // now you have: { "Driver": a, "Lap": b, "Position": c, "newProperty": d }
```

Add a dynamic property as:

```
myObject[dynamicProperty] = e; // now if your dynamic property is 'test', your object is: { "Driver": a, "Lap": b, "Position": c, "newProperty": d, "test": e }
```

Comment: why lose the double quotes..., technically json is supposed to have them, js just doesnt require them

Comment: @PootieTang Gotcha. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PootieTang JSON isn't JavaScript, it's just a notation. In JavaScript, JSON would be a _string_

Comment: @PootieTang There are actually some case where they are required. For example, you could do `var a = { "a-b" : 1 }` but without the quotes it would be a syntax error.

Comment: yes, it's a notation... a javascript notation... that's three of the 4 letters in json... let's not get nit-picky here i'm not a noob

Comment: yeah matt, i'm the one advocating **for** the quotes.